# PySpark write CSV quote all non-numeric

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, quote

Is there a way to quote only non-numeric columns in the dataframe when output to CSV file using `df.write.csv('path')`?

I know you can use the option `quoteAll=True` to quote all the columns but I only want to quote the string columns.

I am using PySpark 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

> I only want to quote the string columns.

There is currently no parameter in `write.csv` that you can use to specify which columns to quote. However, one workaround is to modify your string columns by adding quotes around the values.

First identify the string columns by iterating over the `dtypes`

```python
string_cols = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t == "string"]
```

Now you can modify these columns by adding a quote as a prefix and suffix:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, concat

cols = [
    concat(lit('"'), col(c), lit('"')) if c in string_cols else col(c) 
    for c in df.columns
]

df = df.select(*cols)
```

Finally write out the csv:

```python
df.write.csv('path')
```

Comment: Does this handle the case that the original string containing the double quotation mark (") character by itself?

Comment: It will not work in that case. There are possible workaround, but it depends on what your desired output is. One option would be to escape quotation marks that appear in the string columns.